# CP command making recursive directories

Tags: linux, cp

Okay so what I'm trying to do is that I have a file and I have to replace about 100 files in the location: `/home/*/service*/files/` using that file recursively.

I used the following command:

```
cp -r File.txt /home/*/service*/files
cp: overwrite `/home/xxx/servicexxx/files/CustomCommands.txt'? y
cp: overwrite `/home/xxx/servicexxx/files/files/tips.txt'? ^C
```

Why is it creating a "files" folder inside a files folder instead of just replacing the already existing file. If I don't use the "-r" switch, it copies correctly but omits the other 99 directories showing "**cp ommiting directory**"

Secondly, I have to use the same method to replace a running binary file so that it would automatically switch to the new file next time the file is run. But I get this error:

```
cp: cannot create regular file `xxx': Text file busy
```

Comment: This is not going to work like this. You can copy one source to one destination or multiple sources to one directory, but not one source file to multiple destination files.

Comment: I understand but why would it show the files copied correctly without the "-r" switch but just omit the rest of them. I actually have to replace 100 files with 1 file. Any shortcuts?

Comment: Question fixed and answer added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You confusion here lies in how cp interprets arguments, and how shell expansion works.  First, let's talk about shell expansion.  Consider that you have a simplified directory/file structure that looks like:

```
/home/user1/service1/files/file1.txt
/home/user7/service100/files/file2.txt
/home/user22/service7/files/file3.txt
```

Now consider your command:

```
cp -r File.txt /home/*/service*/files
```

The shell will expand the second argument based on the files it can match *before* executing cp.  You can see this working by replacing `cp` with `echo`.  The actual command you are running is:

```
cp -r File.txt /home/user1/service1/files /home/user7/service100/files /home/user22/service7/files
```

The way the `cp` command works is to copy one or multiple sources into a **single** target, so what you're doing is copying the first three arguments into the last argument: `/home/user22/service7/files`.

Looking this all over again it explains exactly why your file is correctly copied to the last directory, and you get a smattering of `cp: ommiting directory` errors.

To achieve something like what you're looking to do, you could use a `for` loop:

```
for target in /home/*/service*/files/; do
    cp -v File.txt $target
done
```

The `Text File Busy` error is covered a bit in the link below and is probably an artifact of your flawed use of `cp`.  I suspect a for loop like the above would be adequate for your binary replacement as well.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638283/can-text-file-busy-happen-when-two-processes-trying-to-execute-a-perl-file-in

Comment: Semi colon missing after $target though.

Answer (score 2):

This is not going to work like this. You can copy one source to one destination or multiple sources to one directory, but not one source file to multiple destination files.

For the copy problem, employ the help of `find`, `grep` and `xargs`:

```
find /home -type f | grep \/home\/[[:alnum:]]+\/service[[:alnum:]]*\/ | xargs -l1 cp sourcefile
```

but check first if all the right files are matched, eg. by removing the last pipe with the `xargs`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the second part working by using the "cp -f" option which did overwrite the running file. But I'm still not sure about the recursion issue.